# Choosing the right capacitor

Tags: capacitor, design, supercapacitor

I have been told that in order to not damage a battery is better to connect it to a capacitor, to deliver current in a smooth way. This is because we are using a circuit where a peak of current is delivered periodically (16Hz) and this is about 60mA and last 25ms. When the device is not sending a peak the current leech is about 20mA. So the peaks damages the battery. The question is, what type of capacitor I need to choose in order to prevent damaging the battery, what is your basis?. The battery nominal voltage is 3.6V.
The battery's datasheet can be found in: http://www.eemb.com/Download/Primary-Battery/Li-SOCI2-Battery/Energy-Type/ER341245.pdf

Comment: What kind of battery are you using?  I can't think of any battery that is damaged by 60 mA and fine with 20 mA continuous.

Comment: What damages the battery, and also compromises stability, is not the average current of 20 or 60 mA, but the very brief current spikes that are created by digital circuits when switching between 0 and 1. They can have amplitude of several amperes and that is why every digital IC must have a capacitor right at its supply pins.

Comment: I'm using this battery, http://www.eemb.com/Download/Primary-Battery/Li-SOCI2-Battery/Energy-Type/ER341245.pdf
And venny, u think that rising between 20 continuous to peaks of 60mA can compromise the battery?

Comment: How long do the 60mA peaks last? That is important information if you want to maintain a much lower average discharge rate.

Comment: The peak last 25ms and its frequency is 16Hz.

Comment: It's better to update your question with extra information about battery data sheet and circuit peaks, rather than put it into comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ER341245 data sheet](http://www.eemb.com/Download/Primary-Battery/Li-SOCI2-Battery/Energy-Type/ER341245.pdf) says it can supply 450mA continuous, and 1000mA pulse.

So it does *not* look like a capacitor is needed to protect it from damage by a 60mA peak.

According to the data sheet the battery capacity is quite sensitive to the discharge rate, so trying to smooth out the discharge rate might have some benefit.

"peak last 25ms and its frequency is 16Hz"

So every 62.5ms, there is a 25ms peak.

The average current appears to be 38mA (25ms * 60mA + 37.5ms * 20mA)

The peak seems to be too large a fraction of the time, and not much bigger than the normal current flow to make a lot of difference.

I would have to do some experiments to discover how much, if any, improvement a capacitor used to smooth out the peak would have on that batteries capacity.

Put another way, the batteries 'standard' discharge is 2mA, and it falls from 36Ah to 25Ah, about 1/3rd, by increasing the discharge rate by a factor of 50. (*50x* faster discharge, *1/3rd* less capacity)

A 'perfectly smooth' discharge rate would be 38mA, which is about 2/3rd of the peak 60mA, so any improvement in capacity might be hard to detect.

Comment: Gbulmer, you are saying that adding a capacitor will not improve battery life? Or that's difficult to analyze the effect of capacitor when connecting to the battery?

Comment: @progloverfan - I am saying a capacitor *might* improve battery life, but the difference might be so small that it is hard to measure. Also the datasheet carries *no evidence* that pulses as small as 20mA to 60mA will harm the battery. The datasheet shows a *50x* bigger continuos drain (2mA to 100mA) degraded battery life by only 1/3rd. Your example is comparing a pulsed current ratio of 3:1 vs continuos 2:2. This has to be balanced with the extra cost and complexity of the capacitor circuit, and its loses. Measure it, but I'd guess a few degrees ambient temperature change might matter more.